# tar delete progress question

Tags: tar

I was trying to use **tar** command , `--delete` option and met some problems. There are two things I don't understand:

1. when using `--verbose` option with combination of --delete option, nothing shows as `--verbose` usually do, i.e. no show of deleted files.
2. when using `--totals` option, the deleted size is always 0, it doesn't make sense and I can't figure out the meaning of these output.

Can anyone help me with these? The following code shows the procedure.

```
x@x:~/bin$ tar --list --file=pomo.tar
pomodoro
pomodoro_2
pomodoro_3
x@x:~/bin$ tar --append --file=pomo.tar quitpomo --verbose
quitpomo
x@x:~/bin$ tar --list --file=pomo.tar
pomodoro
pomodoro_2
pomodoro_3
quitpomo
x@x:~/bin$ tar --list --file=pomo.tar --totals
pomodoro
pomodoro_2
pomodoro_3
quitpomo
Total bytes read: 10240 (10KiB, 12MiB/s)
x@x:~/bin$ tar --delete --file=pomo.tar quitpomo --total --verbose
Total bytes read: 10240 (10KiB, 86MiB/s)
Total bytes written: 10240 (10KiB, 86MiB/s)
Total bytes deleted: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the size of the `.tar` file before and after the `--delete`, you will see that there is no change in filesize. Hence the total bytes deleted is 0.

If you make the file `quitpomo` larger ( I tried 20480 bytes ), add it and then delete it using the same commands, you will have a non-zero "Total bytes deleted"

This is caused by (GNU)tar [using a block structur](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html)e which adds a certain overhead, and deleting something that doesn't change the block count is considered as not having deleted any bytes (relative to the total file size, not of course to the combined size of files stored internal to those blocks).